# Best way to implement audio playback of large mp3 files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, audio, mp3

I'm creating an audio player UI for audiobook mp3 files (with play, pause, skip-to-point features etc). I have had no problems with setting up the user interface.

Given the above controls, I don't know what is the best way to implement the loading and playing of mp3 files - the ability to skip to certain points of the track is essential (either directly or in some round-about way). I have tried many different modules like simpleaudio, pyglet, pygame (which I would rather avoid), and pydub (ideally I would like a cross-platform solution).

Even when I get mp3s to play, however, the problem is that the audiobook files can sometimes be an hour or more long. When loading these files, it takes a while to process - not making for a seamless experience. I have played around with threading, but the whole mp3 file still needs to load before it plays (rather than, say, loading the first 5 seconds and playing those).

I would be very grateful for general / ball-park advice on how to approach these problems - the best way to load large mp3 files efficiently, and some module which supports 'chunking' of audio so I can simulate skipping.

I have thought about converting to wav to play raw audio (which from what I read seems easier), but I am not sure whether conversion on-the-fly will be more inefficient?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out VLC and it's Python module, python-vlc

Comment: That looks good, thank you, it has all the functionality I need! It is ok for my purposes but is there an alternative that don't require the user to install VLC?

Comment: Well, I'm sure there are, but I've only ever used VLC. Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169666/cross-platform-audio-playback-in-python?rq=1) yet?

Comment: Yeah, I struggled to get gstreamer set up, but I'll leave it until I'm more advanced. I've got everything implemented with VLC and python bindings for now - thank you again!